# Setting variables in SELECT statement mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I'd like to know if it's OK to assume that the `SELECT` statement **selects the fields from left to right** to make sure that it is safe to construct a statement as the following (it wouldn't be nice to try to use a variable that has't been set):

```
SELECT @variable := IFNULL(var, 0), value + @variable, somevalue, value2*@variable, ..., @variable/whatever...

FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 LEFT JOIN table3
```

The reason I'm asking the question is because it is possible that var equals null in some of the tuples due the use of the LEFT JOINS (let's suppose that var comes from table 3), and I need to use the variable several times to make derivative fields as you can see, so I don't want to use IFNULL(var, 0) every time.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the vote down, I'm newbie to sql but I don't consider the question to be irrelevant or silly!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) (with **my** emphasis):

> As a general rule, other than in `SET` statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:

```
SET @a = @a + 1;
```

> For other statements, such as `SELECT`, you **might** get the results you
>   expect, but this is **not guaranteed**. In the following statement, you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:

```
SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
```

> However, **the order of evaluation for expressions involving user
>   variables is undefined**.

So, if we go *by the book*, the answer to your question is **NO**.

Comment: Ok, I have read a book about mysql but there wasn't any mention of what you just explained. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear.  There are plenty of examples that use multiple in-line assignments in the same `SELECT` statement quite successfully (including here, on SO). But it all is in the ***might*** category.